# EF Core - ContainsAsync verification is failed. Duplicated registers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My code verifies if an item already exists on database. If it doesn't exist, it'll be added.

```
foreach(var element in elements)
{
  var item = new Item
  {
    Id = element.Id,
    ...
  }

  if (!await context.Itens.ContainsAsync(new Item { Id = item.Id }))
    await context.Itens.AddAsync(item);
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Note that the items are created inside a foreach loop and the context changes are saved out of the loop. This code does not working properly. I'm having duplicated items on my database.

Maybe the ContainsAsync method is just verifying on database, but not on DbSet?

Comment: Isn't `Id` the primary key?

Comment: `new Item { Id = item.Id }` will never be equal to any item in `context.Items` because it's based on object equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach(var element in elements)
{
  

  if ((await context.Itens.FindAsync(element.Id)!=null)
{
var item = new Item
  {
    Id = element.Id,
    ...
  }
    context.Itens.Add(item);
}
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

if you don't need to check Id in DB, just create list of the items and add them there each time checking if it already exist:

```
var items= List<Item>();

foreach(var element in elements)
{
  

  if (!items.Any(i=>i.Id==elementId))
{

var item = new Item
  {
    Id = element.Id,
    ...
  }
    items.Add(item);
}
}

  context.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

or if you have millions elements then

```
var items= List<Item>();

foreach(var element in elements)
{
  
var item = new Item
  {
    Id = element.Id,
    ...
  }
    items.Add(item);
}

var distinctItems = items.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());

  context.Items.AddRange(distinctItems.ToArray());
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item> {

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
         // &&  x.Name == y.Name;
     }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj) {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() 
        //  ^  obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^
      }
}
```

Comment: Find is only efficient if they've already loaded the entities into memory, otherwise they'll be making a query against the DB each time.

Comment: "If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. " from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-3.1 . The same for Find.

Comment: yes thats what I said `Find` is only efficient, if the entities is already loaded into memory.  If the op didn't load any of the entities it will make a request each time to the DB

Comment: If you don't need to check Id in DB just create list of the items and add them there each time checking if it already exist. After this use AddRange(items) and SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do that in one query and transaction is needed.

```
await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

var items = elements.Select(element => new Item
{
   Id = element.Id,
   ...
}).ToList();

// Ids to test
var toTest = items.Select(item => item.Id).ToList();

// select Ids that are already in database
var existing = await context.Items
   .Where(item => toTest.Contains(item.Id))
   .Select(item => item.Id)
   .ToListAsync();

var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(existing);

foreach(var element in items.Where(item => !hashSet.Contains(existing)))
{
    context.Items.Add(item);
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

await transaction.CommitAsync();
```

Not ideal solution. But it is how EF Core is designed.

Answer (score 0):

The query you're doing is inefficient because you're looping your queries instead of making a single one, and it doesn't take object equality into account.

```
var itemIds = elements.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
var existingItemIds = await context.Items
        .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .ToArrayAsync();

var missingItemIds = itemIds.Except(existingItemIds).ToArray();

foreach(var itemId in missingItemIds)
{
   context.Items.Add(new Item {Id = itemId });
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Instead of looping each time you made a single query to obtain the itemIds which do exist, and then filter them out.

**Note:** What I find weird is that the Item's already have an Id. Generally it's the DB which creates the Ids.  Are you sure you don't want to just create items for the one with an Id of 0?